# Assign Django variable value to AngularJS

Tags: html, django, angularjs

I have this template tags in my html code

```
{{ djangoVar}}   //Django template tag
{$ angularVar $} //AngularJS template tag
```

How can I assign `{{ djangoVar}}` to `{$ angularVar $}` in my html?

Something like:

```
{% {$ angularVar $} = djangoVar %}
```

Comment: `{$ angularVar = {{ djangoVar }} $}` maybe?!

Answer (score 2):

The angularVar must be assigned with javascript code. So, in your django template you can do something like

```
<script>
var django_variables = {};
django_variables.djangoVar = {{ djangoVar }};
</script>
```

So you declare a `django_variables` global variable. Then, in your angular controllers you can do:

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.angularVar = django_variables.djangoVar;
}
```

The important thing is to run the 1st snippet inside a normal django html template that the context will be passed and `{{ djangoVar }}` will get its value.

Comment: any other method, this method seems dirty.

Comment: There's no other way! You'll end up doing something like what I propose.